# About the differences between 貯金 and 節約

Tags: word-choice, words, word-usage

As the title says, I would like to know differences between 貯金{ちょきん} and 節約{せつやく}.
Both mean "saving money" and have the irregular する verb ending:

> 貯金する{ちょきんする} : To save money
>
> 節約する{せつやくする} : To save money

From what I understand by reading example sentences, 節約{せつやく} has a more general meaning and can be used with anything to save like water, food, money...

Is 貯金 only usable with a *money* context? Are there any differences between the two of them when they are used in a *money* context?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69964/9831

Answer (score 6, accepted):

貯金 = to put money in the bank or a piggy bank or envelope.

節約 = to avoid spending money (i.e., to make food rather than eat out)

Both of these are [漢語]{かんご} (Chinese words in Japanese).

貯金 follows a verb-object pattern. Thus,

```
 貯(v) store  金(object) - money
```

節約 follows a duplication pattern:

```
 節(v)  -save 約 - save
```

So you can do lots of things to 節約, but if you are talking about water, people say [節水]{せっすい} or about electricity [節電]{せつでん}. In those cases, it means "reduce use of X"

Comment: You can do 貯金 using a piggy bank or an envelope, too.

Comment: @naruto okay amended!